# WPF Binding to a property of a custom control

Tags: wpf, binding, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I've created a custom control, means a class deriving from control associating a default lookless theme defined via Themes/Generic.xaml. So far so good.

Now, I want to use the control like any other of the main WPF-controls (textbox, listbox, label, textblock, ...) and bind to the defined properties.

The custom control defines a property called Value, that I like to set a Binding to. But nothing ever is written to the bound property in the DataContext.

Well, here's what I've got so far:

In Custom Control class, there is as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Value", typeof(string), typeof(MyClass),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(onValuePropertyChangedCallback)));

private static void onValuePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    MyClass myClass = (MyClass)sender;
    myClass.Value = (string)args.NewValue;
}

public string Value
{
    get { return (string) GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}
```

When I use the control, it's like that

```
<local:MyClass MyValue="{Binding CurrentValue}" ... />
```

The CurrentValue-property of the DataContext is never affected, never changes it's value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Binding to should be two-way in order to update the source property:

```
<local:MyClass Value="{Binding CurrentValue, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
```

If you want this to be the default binding mode, you could set an appropriate flag when you register your property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Value), typeof(string), typeof(MyClass),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        "", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public string Value
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}
```

Note that your `onValuePropertyChangedCallback` was entirely redundant. You don't need to set the property again, when its value has just changed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was assuming, that the BindingMode is TwoWay by default. Now, that I've set the BindingMode, everything works fine. Thanks again!